# Flash memory read and write

Tags: c, arm, embedded, flash, cortex-m3

I'm always disabling interrupts while writing to some sectors on Flash, but does Flash memory requires disabled interrupts even when you just want to read from it? Why yes and why not? Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to disable interrupts to read from Flash. Reading Flash is just like reading RAM. It's only writing which is different: inside the device a "high voltage" (just a couple of volts extra, really) is generated for the gate, and that gate voltage needs there to be longer than just a few nanoseconds to charge the floating gate. That is self-timed by the device.

Comment: I'm having a problem when writing to flash, my data which i have written to some sector, when try to read from the same address I'm getting FF value. What all can cause data to not be written? I tried everything on my mind and still not working.

Comment: @Lazar The original question that you asked has been answered. Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information. To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: I thought that I will exceed the question limit if I always make a new question for the similar topics.